# div onclick function to change body background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want a small picture that acts like a button, to be click-able with a function to change the body background-image. I am a total newbie and I'm trying to learn. The most simple way, I thought, would be to have a div with a `background-image`.
I have to use unsemantic grid, also.

So I pretty much only have the div with a background image. How do I write this function? I'm sure it's really easy and I've read like 20 threads here but none of them were useful for me

Edit: added my code

```css
#knapp {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-image:url(http://ingridwu.dmmdmcfatter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/placeholder.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain; 
  position:absolute;
  top:90vh;
  right:3vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="knapp" class="grid-10 prefix-90"></div>
```

Comment: Here's the methods you'd need to use: http://api.jquery.com/click & http://api.jquery.com/css

Comment: you need to include some code, what have you tried already? or at least your HTML

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to make sense of that long text. English isn't my native tongue.

Comment: Your English and question is clear but you at least provide some attemp

Comment: I edited and added some info

Comment: Edited my answer to (hopefully) work with your code. It all relies on you having hardcoded array of image addresses, though, so I hope that isn't inconvenient. Thanks for adding the code!

Comment: What image should `body` `background` be set to ?

Comment: It should be set to a local file called bakgrundbild-alt.png

Comment: @guest271314 Oh. I thought he wanted to *cycle* through multiple images. My bad.

Comment: Well to cycle them would be even better actually, I just didn't think of that myself

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Add cursor on the div to appear clickable

```
   #knapp {
      cursor: pointer;
   }
```

You could put the new background-image in a new css rule

```
body.newbg {
    background-image:url(path-to-new-background.png);
}
```

This is body with the old background-image

```
body {
    background-image:url(path-to-old-background.png);
}
```

and with jquery just add/toggle the class by doing something like that (in `$(document).ready()`):

```
$('#knapp').on('click', function(){

    $('body').addClass('newbg');
    // you could instead do toggleClass if you want for each click to have background switch between old background and new background
});
```

This is a cleaner approach compared to all the other answers as it separates presentation (css), structure (html) and behavior (javascript).
This is because it doesn't use JavaScript to change style directly. Also it doesn't pollute html with onclick which is also a bad practice.

Here is a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/aiGZmvvi6WWGFs7E9xTp

and here is one with a circular collection of backgrounds (thanks to Kai's idea)
https://plnkr.co/edit/0djmmNM9OOTdfYyvLvUH?p=preview

Comment: Don't I have to change the html anything? This seemes like a good solution but the only problem is you cant click on the div, since it's not a link or anything

Comment: you can put click to anything it doesn't have to be a link ;) you can change your cursor to be pointer if you want it to appear as clickable

Comment: @AliceHolmerLazar I updated the answer so you can change the cursor on :hover to be a pointer

Comment: Wait, this changes the background of the button, not the body?

Comment: Thanks @KaiChristensen

Comment: This was very helpful! It doesn't work yet, maybe becauise of something I have mistyped or missed, but this made sense even to me, a total beginner with jquery. :)

Comment: Would you mind if I shared the files with you so you could have a look? It feels like it's supposed to work

Comment: @AliceHolmerLazar most probably you forgot to put the binding of on click event after html has finished rendering (```$(document).ready```) - added it in the answer - check my plunkr and let me know if more help is needed :)

Comment: @MichailMichailidis May be helpful to OP to describe difference between approaches of using `.addClass()` and `.toggleClass()`; where plnkr uses `.toggleClass()` though Answer uses `.addClass()`

Comment: @guest271314 those are very well documented (https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ & https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) - and if you have seen I had already a comment in the code- I am expecting the OP to express any further questions she might have otherwise my answer would be too long and not very useful.

Comment: @AliceHolmerLazar I added an extra plunkr that circulates over a fixed collection of backgrounds defined in css using the same code structure :)

Comment: hm this made less sense to me, but i have several problems with the code, not only in tje jquery file. i problably screwed up from the start. here's a link to the files if anyone wants to check them out: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue

Comment: @AliceHolmerLazar you need to save the link so it has an id and we can see it

Comment: @AliceHolmerLazar https://plnkr.co/edit/ZVjWbepxKcBnmMs7ZOaj?p=preview here it is working.. you had local style and script urls and no jquery in the plunkr html. also your clickable div was empty so I added some red text. your script had a mistake too. Make sure the plunkrs you will be making in the future don't have local urls.. since those won't work - everything needs to be local to plunkr :)

Comment: it's working, kind of. now, when i load the page there is no bg. but atfer i press the button it starts to toggle

Comment: @AliceHolmerLazar did you put bg-0 class on body so it has background for the first time? My plunkr has background the first time.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a button with `onclick` attribute with a function name like `replace`.
2. Defined the function in your script like:

   ```
   function replace() {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://lh6.ggpht.com/8mgTDZXaLMS1JsnF28Tjh6dahHwN1FqcXCVnifkfppmNLqnD-mPBuf9C1sEWhlEbA4s=w300)';  
   }
   ```

Explanation:

You set the `style` property of the body (using `document.body` object) to other `background-image`.

If something is not clear, I will happy to explain.

**Working example:**

```js
function replace() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://lh6.ggpht.com/8mgTDZXaLMS1JsnF28Tjh6dahHwN1FqcXCVnifkfppmNLqnD-mPBuf9C1sEWhlEbA4s=w300)';  
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://www.julienlevesque.net/preview/google-smile-preview.jpg);
}

div {
  background:blue;
  color:#fff;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="replace()">Replace background-image</div>
```

Comment: I tried to use a button instead of a div but that doesn't work since it's not supposed to be a button but a clickable image

Comment: I was updated my answer.. It doesn't matter because you can set `onclick` on div too..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, you should be able to create a variable in jQuery which is an array of all the string versions of your image urls that you want to use:

`var images = ['../images/####','../images/$$$$', 'http://some.other/url.here];`

`// do this for as many images as you want to cycle through`

Like that.

Then you can make a counter variable:

`var counter = 0;`

and set it to zero.

Next, add the event listener `on()` to your `div` like this:

```
$('#knapp').on('click', function(){



});
```

Finally, inside your event listener, change the CSS `background-image` property of the div to one of your images in the array:

```
// do this inside a document.ready() function
$('#knapp').on('click', function(){

    $(this).css('background-image','url("' + images[counter] + '")');
    counter++;

});
```

I hope this helped! Also, remember to increment `counter`

***EDIT ----------------------------------------------------------------***

OK, so I totally jumped over something obvious which is the fact that the counter might go too high and access something out of scope. To prevent this add the following inside of your `on()` listener:

```
if(counter >= images.length - 1){

    counter = 0;

}
```

***EDIT 2 --------------------------------------------------------------***

Ok, so I didn't know what exactly you were asking at first, so here is my second answer. Since it seems like what you are actually trying to do is only switch the background image once on click, then you could use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#knapp').on('click', function(){

        $(this).css('background-image','url("YOUR_NEW_URL_HERE")');

});

});
```

or you could have it toggle between two images by making two identical classes in CSS (except for the background image) and replacing one with the other using `.addClass` and `.removeClass`.

***EDIT 3---------------------------------------------------------------***

I never thought I would edit this post this many times, but apparently I missed that the `body` background image should be changed (thanks to comments). My bad and thanks for pointing it out (even if you were talking to someone else).

Comment: I added your circular background idea to an extra plunkr! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help Kai although I went with the other suggestion since it seemed easier and more logical. https://plnkr.co/edit/eOClcBGhKPz2UoS8oHXm?p=catalogue here's the result. Still doesn't work. I must have done something wrong from the start

Answer (score 1):

This may help you...

```
$('.yourClassofDiv').click({
   $(this).css("background-image",'url("' + URLofIMAGE+ '")')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `onclick` at `div#knapp` element , set `document.body.style.background` to url of image file

```css
#knapp {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain; 
  position:absolute;
  top:90vh;
  right:3vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="knapp" class="grid-10 prefix-90" onclick="document.body.style.background = 'url(http://lorempixel.com/'+ window.innerWidth + '/'+ window.innerHeight +') no-repeat'"></div>
```

Comment: this answer while concise couples javascript with html and css ..so I believe is not a good idea for a new developer to start with bad technique from day one.

Comment: @MichailMichailidis you can't downvote just because you `believe is a bad practice`. Please comment and let the user to explain you his thoughts..

Comment: I don't believe - it is a very bad practice

Comment: @MichailMichailidis Version separating `js` from `html` plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/GS9Bysy7trku1MvRN7SZ?p=preview

Comment: @guest271314 you are still using js to change style directly - which for this small example is really not needed - your plunkr is making js do what css's job is to do

Comment: @MichailMichailidis _"I don't believe - it is a very bad practice"_ In your opinion, is all use of `on` event handlers within `html` "very bad practice" ?

Comment: @MichailMichailidis _"you are still using js to change style directly - which for this small example is making js do what css should do"_ ? Should a `css` only approach be used ?

Comment: no it is not - it is an old practice at least 15 years old - that needs at some point to stop :)

Comment: @MichailMichailidis _"no it is not - it is an old practice at least 15 years old - that needs at some point to stop :)"_ ? Is this a crusade ? Do you "downvote" every Answer at SO which includes `on`-event handlers in `html` ?

Comment: @guest271314 see my example I use js to just add a class - and css takes care of what that means.. makes the code more flexible more concise and separates all the concerns of structure (html), presentation(css) and behavior(js)

Comment: @MichailMichailidis If you make an argument about using `js` within `html` , it is only fair to point out that your solution loads an entire library (jQuery) to use `.on()` ? How is loading an entire library to attach an event not "bad practice" ?

Comment: @guest271314 not really I don't have that much free time - I just did because reputation tends to be connected with more experience and more correct answers. This is a new developer that if he starts using bad practices from day one he will continue those 10-15 year old techniques when he goes to work for a company

Comment: @MichailMichailidis fwiw, using event handlers within `html` is not deprecated. What does working for a company have to do with the present Question ?

Comment: @MichailMichailidis Also note, your posted solution does not change the `background` of `body` element ? See OP at _"to change the body background-image"_ Perhaps "downvote" yourself ?

Comment: @MichailMichailidis Curious, what is the source, reference of the phrase _"it is a very bad practice"_ ? Or is this your opinion ?

Comment: Some random sources that are basically hundreds but we are in stackoverflow: http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns etc

Comment: @MichailMichailidis The phrase _"it is a very bad practice"_ does not appear at linked pages ?

Comment: @guest271314 drop "very" if that makes you happy. I don't have time to play with words

Comment: @MichailMichailidis _"drop "very" if that makes you happy. I don't have time to play with words"_ ? Those are _your_ words. Seeking to affirm correct attribution for the phrase _"it is a very bad practice"_ . No games or "play", whatsoever, here. Not about "happy"; you begat this exchange; only attempting to clarify the source of your posted comment. At present, would have to attribute _"it is a very bad practice"_ to you

Comment: @guest271314 can you find me a single source that says that your practice is good? I gave four sources and I can send way more that indicate that your code is towards practices that lead to problems.

Comment: @MichailMichailidis _"can you find me a single source that says that your practice is good?"_ The original Question is not about whether or not including inline event handlers within `html` is a "good" or "bad" practice.

Comment: @guest271314 you must be a part-time lawyer - I would like to spend more time on coding and reading good practices books than arguing about words

Comment: @guest271314  I have seen a lot of applications, costing millions to make thrown away, using similar coding practices that made the technical debt unsustainable. Bad code eventually costs a LOT of money, I hope you agree with that at least

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple way in jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").css('background-image', 'url(http://julienlevesque.net/Requiem/images/detail-requiem.jpg)').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
  $('div').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
        $("body").css('background-image', 'url(http://julienlevesque.net/Requiem/images/Requiem-Julien-Levesque.jpg)');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div style="background-color:yellow">Click Here to change background Image</div>
</body>
```

Here i will explain the code.
The jQuery syntax is tailor made for selecting HTML elements and performing some action on the element(s).

Basic syntax is: `$(selector).action()`

```
A $ sign to define/access jQuery
A (selector) to "query (or find)" HTML elements
A jQuery action() to be performed on the element(s)

$(this).hide() - hides the current element.

$("p").hide() - hides all <p> elements.

$(".test").hide() - hides all elements with class="test".

$("#test").hide() - hides the element with id="test".
```

Here is what happen in the code.

1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // jQuery methods go here...

});
```

This is to prevent any jQuery code from running before the document is finished loading (is ready).It is good practice to wait for the document to be fully loaded and ready before working with it. This also allows you to have your JavaScript code before the body of your document, in the head section.

2

```
$("body").css('background-image', 'url(http://julienlevesque.net/Requiem/images/detail-requiem.jpg)').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
```

getting the body element of your html and set its background-image with `.css()` action. which i gave it more one action

3

```
$('div').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
        $("body").css('background-image', 'url(http://julienlevesque.net/Requiem/images/Requiem-Julien-Levesque.jpg)');
    });
```

this is where the change takes place. i got the `div` to be `clicked` by `$('div')` and first gave it an action of changing the mouse to cursor to indicate its clickable and then gave it the click function, where our background-image get changed on click